# How to use global variable in C++ module?

Tags: c++, module, c++20, c++-modules

When I use module in a C++20 project, if I have

```
// Camera.hpp
extern const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH;
extern const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT;
```

And in main.cpp

```
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
```

But now I use module,

```
// Camera.cppm
module;

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

export module Camera;

// extern const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH;
// extern const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT;
```

It seems that the linker cannot find the variables, so how should I revise it?

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: SCR_HEIGHT@Camera
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/src/triangle2.cpp.obj:(.refptr._ZW6Camera10SCR_HEIGHT)

ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: SCR_WIDTH@Camera
>>> referenced by CMakeFiles/triangle.dir/src/triangle2.cpp.obj:(.refptr._ZW6Camera9SCR_WIDTH)
```

Comment: Just as a side note: Retrieving screen dimensions dynamically from the operating system appears more appropriate to me anyway. Not feasible for you?

Comment: "it can't compile" What are the symptoms?

Comment: @Yunnosch, seems that it's linker cannot find the variable. And I added the error message above.

Comment: `const` for variables  in file scope implies `static`. While you can trick it wuth usual header, it lies outside of module's functionality. THings declared in modules, should be defiend in module.

Comment: 3. `module;` just states that this source contains a module. It must appear before everything else, so the compiler knows. 4. Modules, namespaces, and classes *can* all have the same name. If it looks confusing, then just use different names. It is up to you.

Comment: Your declarations of those variables are commented out _and_ are not definitions.  Clarify, please?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie: The implicit `static` is a pre-C++17 hack that is nonsensical in modules and [has been removed there](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2023/p2788r0.html).

Comment: @DavisHerring perhaps I worded it wrong, I know that but was barely awake. It looked like OP declared them outside of module but planned define them inside